# Getting Gamestate value in State Monad

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I'm learning about state monads and i'm a little confused.

I have a data type

```
data GameState = GameState (Map String Double) Double Bool
deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The second argument Double is a direction

and of course the state monad definition

```
newtype State s a = StateOf (s -> (s, a))
deState (StateOf stf) = stf
get = StateOf (\s0 -> (s0, s0))
put s = StateOf (\s0 -> (s , ()))
modify f = get >>= \s -> put (f s)
```

So how do I write a function to get the direction

```
getDirection:: State GameState Double
```

I've tried

```
getDirection = do
     x <- get
     return x
```

But this will just return GameState, how do I get what the direction currently is?

And when I want to change the direction do I use put or modify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s start with what you have so far:

```hs
getDirection :: State GameState Double
getDirection = do
     x <- get
     return x
```

(As an aside, this is really just the same as `getDirection = get`, since you’re simply running `get` and returning its return value.)

Firstly, what is the type of `x` here? Your state is of type `GameState`, and `get` just gets the state, so `x :: GameState`. So we can pattern match on it to get:

```hs
getDirection :: State GameState Double
getDirection = do
     (GameState map dir bool) <- get
     return (GameState map dir bool)
```

At this point it should be obvious what to do: simply return `dir` instead of `(GameState map dir bool)`.

> And when I want to change the direction do I use put or modify?

You shouldn’t really ask two questions in the same post, but to answer this, let’s have a look at their types:

```hs
put    :: s        -> State s ()
modify :: (s -> s) -> State s ()
```

The idea is that `put` simply writes a new state, whereas `modify` takes the existing state and modifies it using the given function. These functions are in fact equivalent in power, meaning you can replace either function with the other:

```hs
-- write ‘put’ using ‘modify’
put s = modify (\_oldState -> s)

-- write ‘modify’ using ‘put’ (and ‘get’)
modify f = do
    oldState <- get
    put $ f oldState
```

However, usually it is easier to use `put` or `modify` in different situations. For instance, if you want to write a completely new state without reference to the old state, use `put`; if you want to take the existing state and change it a bit, use `modify`. In your case, you want to change the direction only, so it’s easiest to use `modify` so you can change the state with reference to what it used to be:

```hs
changeDirTo :: Double -> State GameState ()
changeDirTo newDir = modify (\(GameState map _ bool) -> GameState map newDir bool)

-- you can also do it using ‘put’, but it’s a bit harder and less elegant:
changeDirTo2 :: Direction -> State GameState ()
changeDirTo2 newDir = do
    (GameState map _ bool) <- get
    put $ GameState map newDir bool
```

On the other hand, if you (say) wanted to assign a completely new `GameState`, `put` would be easier:

```hs
putNewGameState :: GameState -> State GameState ()
putNewGameState gs = put gs

-- the above is the same as:
-- putNewGameState = put

-- you can also do it using ‘modify’, but it’s a bit harder and less elegant:
putNewGameState2 :: GameState -> State GameState ()
putNewGameState2 gs = put (\_oldState -> gs)
```

Comment: You’re welcome @all! If you find this answer helps, can you accept it (click the green check mark) so this question is marked as answered?